# Probability with a table

Tags: statistics

[image]

a) P(randomly picking someone going to the concert)= I have .406 but its wrong

b) P(randomly picking someone who has kids)= I have .54 but it might be wrong

c) P(randomly picking someone who does not have kids, but is going to the
 concert)= I have .61, but it might be wrong

d) P(randomly picking someone not going to the concert, given that the person chosen has kids)= I have .66, but it might be wrong.

e) P(randomly picking someone who does not have kids, given that the person is unsure about going)= I have .4, but it might be wrong.

They need to be in fractions. I think that a might be right but I'm not sure where I went wrong.

Comment: Your results are right, except for c). There you have transposed digits. At a) I would round it to 0.4067 or 0.407. Do you have problems to write the results in fractions ?